# Add upon constructor from base class in subclass

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

I was messing around with c++ classes when I ran into an issue. I am trying to make a player class inherit from the Entity class and mix their constructors. The entity class has a constructor that requires you to provide the x position float and the y position float. I want the Player class to require x and y position too, but I also want the name to be required. How would I do this?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Entity{
public:
    float x, y;
    int health = 30;
    
    Entity(float X, float Y){
        std::cout << "Entity Constructed!" << std::endl;
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }
    
    ~Entity(){
        std::cout << "Entity Destructed!" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void Print(){
        std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
    }
    
    void Move(float mx, float my){
        x+=mx;
        y+=my;
    }
};

class Player : public Entity{
public:
    const char* Name;
    int attack_damage = 5;
    
    Player(const char* name){
        Name = name;
    }
    
    void Attack(Entity& entity){
        entity.health-=attack_damage;
    }
};

int main(){
    Entity e(0.0f, 0.0f);
    Player p(0.0f,0.0f);
    std::cout << e.health << std::endl;
    p.Attack(e);
    std::cout << e.health << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

and here is the error message I got when I tried to compile the code provided above:

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/learning-cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/c++    -Wall -Werror -std=c++14 -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/learning-cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/learning-cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/learning-cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o -c src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp: In constructor ‘Player::Player(const char*)’:
src/main.cpp:33:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘Entity::Entity()’
     Player(const char* name){
                             ^
src/main.cpp:8:5: note: candidate: ‘Entity::Entity(float, float)’
     Entity(float X, float Y){
     ^~~~~~
src/main.cpp:8:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
src/main.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Entity::Entity(const Entity&)’
 class Entity{
       ^~~~~~
src/main.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/main.cpp:44:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘Player::Player(float, float)’
     Player p(0.0f,0.0f);
                       ^
src/main.cpp:33:5: note: candidate: ‘Player::Player(const char*)’
     Player(const char* name){
     ^~~~~~
src/main.cpp:33:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
src/main.cpp:28:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Player::Player(const Player&)’
 class Player : public Entity{
       ^~~~~~
src/main.cpp:28:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
src/main.cpp:28:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Player::Player(Player&&)’
src/main.cpp:28:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the base class's constructor arguments in the subclass's initializer list: `Player(char const* name, double, x, double y): Entity(x, y), name(name) {}`. I find most of the constructors I write have an empty body and everything gets initialized from the initializer list.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was able to edit it to work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Player(float x, float y, const char* name)
    : Entity(x,y)
{
    Name = name;
}
```